# GXT// How to use BorderLayoutContainer suitbly browser? in GXT 3.0 Beta2

Tags: gwt, gxt

i'm a novice at GXT. Even i am not good at English..

I have a problem with GXT:BorderLayoutContainer
(I use GXT 3.0.0 Beta.2)

I wanna fill up BodrderLayoutConatainer in Browser, but I don't know How to do it.

In GXT 2.4, I can use Fitable, but, 3.0 there are not Fitable.

How can I do this in UiBinder?(in Xml)

Thanks in advance.

//my source

```
<container:SimpleContainer borders="true" styleName="style.test">
    <container:BorderLayoutContainer borders="true" resize="false">
        <container:north>
            <gxt:ContentPanel resize="false" >
                <button:TextButton text="north/contents/Button"></button:TextButton>
            </gxt:ContentPanel>
        </container:north>
        <container:center>
            <container:SimpleContainer resize="false" borders="true"  >
                <button:TextButton text="center/simple/Button" ></button:TextButton>
            </container:SimpleContainer>
        </container:center> 
        <container:south>
            <button:TextButton text="ABC" borders="true"></button:TextButton>
        </container:south>
    </container:BorderLayoutContainer>
</container:SimpleContainer>
```

Dong ju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SimpleContainer is unnecessary in this case. Additionally, when you are using the css classes in the ui:style, make sure you wrap them in {} brackets, so you have `styleName="{style.test}"` instead of `styleName="style.test"`.

But on the topic at hand, add the BorderLayoutContainer to a Viewport, and add that to the page, and it will be sized to the page. This can probably be done in UiBinder, though I haven't tried.

Viewport's job is to size itself (and its children) to the available window space. SimpleContainer sizes its children to itself - it isn't often used when building a UI, but is extended to make other containers (FieldLabel is one example of this).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solve this problem. Problem is BorderLayout's turn. Now, I know that. Center is Last turn, but I not follow.. Thanks for your Advice, Again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'turn', but I think you need to move the <container:center> element until after the <container:south> element. If I am misunderstanding you, it might be good to make a new question with a code sample and the error you are getting. Please accept the answer if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Yes, I can't understanding before because i'm not good at English... So, I'm sure "Wow, I solve this Problem!!". But.. I can't.. Now, I solve this problem to BorderLayoutData and ViewPort. Thank you Colin. If, I have problem again, I waiting your help..
P.S.
Sorry, This is my first stackoverflow so I don't know about accept the answer.. I gonna find Accept your answer Button :)

Comment: The sencha forums might be another good place to post for specific questions about GXT - you probably want to start in the Question/Answer forum http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?100-Ext-GWT-Q-amp-A. The code samples for the uibinder+BorderLayoutContainer might help too http://www.sencha.com/examples-dev/#ExamplePlace:borderlayout%28uibinder%29